# Converting a Date from yyyy/mm/dd to mm/dd/yyyy including GMT Timestamp

Tags: apex, datetime

```
String dateTimeString = '1970-01-08T23:45:27.461Z';
dateTimeString = dateTimeString.substring(0, dateTimeString.indexOf('.'));

system.debug('dateTimeString'+dateTimeString);  results in 1970-01-08T23:45:27

dateTimeString = dateTimeString.replace('T', ' ');

system.debug('dateTimeString'+dateTimeString); results 1970-01-08 23:45:27
```

here the   string representing date in format yyyy-mm-dd 23:45:27   but i want to format it to mm-dd-yyyy 23:45:27  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to do substring or replace on the date. You can use the [Datetime.format()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2) method to get the output in the expected format.

For Example:

```
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now(); // Returns the current Datetime based on a GMT calendar.
String myDate = myDT.format('mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'); // formats the date
system.debug('myDate='+myDate);
```

Comment: thanks.. but i was getting an error  if my input datetime is 1970-01-08 23:45:27 by using your logic it is returning 45-08-1970 23:45:27 in place of 1st month it is displaying 45 i have changed mydt.format to mydt.formatGmt

Comment: seems to be it's projecting minutes mm in place of months mm

Comment: it's working i changed mm to MM

Answer (score 1):

Once you've normalised the date/time string, simply convert it to a `DateTime` variable and format it:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.valueOf(dateTimeString);
dateTimeString = myDateTime.formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

You can [read more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) around other ways to format the date/time and some other [Force.com DateTime methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) available.